# Fetching a variable value from HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html

Below is a code for a kids' webpage, and the program should print a Christmas tree (with optional decorations, code not yet ready for those). When I run it, however, I get an error message saying "Undefined variable: h on line 60".
How can I define it?

And another one, why doesn't my for-loop work? It should print out the following way depending on chosen height:
*
*
***

---

---

...and so on. Now (testing) it obviously prints nothing, and if i manually put it printing 5 times, it puts everything on one line. So I am missing the line feed too, but I don't know how to write it.

Thank you!

```
<html>
<head><title>Christmas Tree Shop</title></head>
<body>
<form>
        echo = "How long a tree would you like to buy (3-12)? "
        
        <input type = "int"  name = "height" placeholder = "Height (3-12)">
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name = "candle" placeholder = "candles (í) ">
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
    </select>
        
    <select name = "bauble" placeholder = "baubles (@) ">
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
    </select>
    
    <select name = "pretzel" placeholder = "pretzels (&) ">
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
    </select>
    <button type = "submit" name = "submit" type = "submit">Purchase</button>

</form>
<p>Here is your tree!</p>

<?php

    $candle = "í";
    $bauble = "@";
    $pretzel = "&";
    
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
       $h = $_GET['height'];
       $candles = $_GET['candle'];
       $baubles = $_GET['bauble'];
       $pretzels = $_GET['pretzel'];
    }
    
    $decorations = array();
    switch ($candle){
        case "Yes":
            $decorations = "í";
    }
    switch ($bauble){
        case "Yes":
            $decorations = "@";
    }
    switch ($pretzel){
        case "Yes":
            $decorations = "&";
    }
    
    $line = $h;
    $star = 1;
    
    echo str_repeat('&nbsp;',$h) . '*' . str_repeat('&nbsp;', $h);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $h ; $i++) {
      echo nl2br(str_repeat($i, '*'));
    }
    
    
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$h` will only be defined/exist if the form is submitted (since you only define it inside that if-statement). You should define it and give it a default value before it, just like you've done with your other variables.

Answer (score 1):

i checked your code $h undefined because you did not define it as you defined others like, i changed the code check this code.

```
<?php

$candle = "í";
$bauble = "@";
$pretzel = "&";
$h = '100'; //what ever height value you need to set its , here i put 100 for example

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
   $h = $_GET['height'];
   $candles = $_GET['candle'];
   $baubles = $_GET['bauble'];
   $pretzels = $_GET['pretzel'];
}
$decorations = array();
switch ($candle){
    case "Yes":
        $decorations = "í";
}
switch ($bauble){
    case "Yes":
        $decorations = "@";
}
switch ($pretzel){
    case "Yes":
        $decorations = "&";
}

$line = $h;
$star = 1;

echo str_repeat('&nbsp;',$h) . '*' . str_repeat('&nbsp;', $h);

for ($i = 0; $i < $h ; $i++) {
  echo nl2br(str_repeat($i, '*'));
}
```

?>